# INSERT INTO statement with select

Tags: postgresql, insert

I am trying to insert a new record into a table, but only if another record of the same table meets some conditions. Sadly it does not work I alwys get the following error: `ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "stackacos_pkey"` Even though the id is not yet present in the db. Any idea how to avoid this issue ?

```
INSERT INTO stackacos (id, created_at, updated_at, owner_id, stack_id, admin_full, admin_create, admin_read, admin_update, admin_delete, "create", read, update, delete) 
SELECT 'notyetindbisforsureunique', '2018-09-18 14:34:57', '2018-09-18 14:34:57', 'test_user_222', 'KZROLZYQbSeHbMtZNFCpMlaKJyfaKFMdcbwGklCiUQBuIiZSptBSlVcuUGofnjMM', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'true', 'false', 'false' 
FROM stackacos 
WHERE stackacos.owner_id = 'test_user_1' AND
    stackacos.admin_full = true OR (
        stackacos.admin_create >= 'false' AND stackacos.admin_create >= 'false' AND
        stackacos.admin_read >= 'false' AND stackacos.admin_read >= 'true' AND
        stackacos.admin_update >= 'false' AND stackacos.admin_update >= 'false' AND
        stackacos.admin_delete >= 'false' AND stackacos.admin_delete >= 'false'
        ) RETURNING *
```

Comment: If the ID is truly a hard-coded value, have you tried running the `SELECT` statement by itself, to ensure that it only returns 1 row? If it returns multiple rows, it would be trying to insert multiple rows - all of which woul dhave the same ID.

Comment: Yeah it only returns 1 row

Comment: Postgres uses the name of constraints as `${table_name}_${column_name}_${constraint_name}`. But there you have custom name. So can you `SELECT pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid) FROM pg_constraint c WHERE conname = 'stackacos_pkey'`?

Answer (score 0):

use nextvalue(idstackacos_find_the_right_sequence_name ) instead of

OLD:

```
SELECT 'notyetindbisforsureunique', '2018-09-18 14:34:57', '2018-09-18 14:34:57'
```

NEW:

```
SELECT nextvalue(idstackacos_find_the_right_sequence_name) , '2018-09-18 14:34:57', '2018-09-18 14:34:57'
```

If it's not working please copy here the definition of the table and of the sequence.